# How to define correct MediaTypes for ResponseBuilder in ExceptionMapper

Tags: cxf

I'm facing following problem:

I'm using CXF for REST services. For exception handling I'm using `javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper` and in `public Response toResponse(T ex)` I want to return some object, for example

```java
class MyObject {
    String detail;
}
```

example implementation of method is similar to

```java
public Response toResponse(T ex) {
    MyObject o = new MyObject();
    o.detail = "...";
    return Response.status(400).entity(o).build();
}
```

but I'm having problem

```
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSOutInterceptor writeResponseErrorMessage
WARNING: No message body writer has been found for response class RequestError.
```

Somehow I found that when I specify MediaType

```java
return Response.status(400).entity(o).type("application/json").build();
```

everything is ok, but I do not know which type client accepts...

Of course I can somewhere store which types client accepts and later use the correct one, but this smells. I'd like to use something nicer.

For example in my CXF endpoint I can specify, using `@Produces`, what kind of MediaTypes my controller method produces and CXF/Spring select the correct one. I tried it in my ExceptionMapper too, but it doesn't work.

Comment: did you get any solution for this issue?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't solve it. I implemented the approach described above "store which types client accepts and later use the correct one".

Answer (score 0):

u can do it like this

```java
@Context HttpHeaders headers;

public Response toResponse(Exception e) {
    ExceptionEntity ee = new ExceptionEntity(e);
    ResponseBuilder rb = Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    rb.type(headers.getMediaType());
    rb.entity(ee);
    Response r = rb.build();
    return r;
}
```

i'm using cxf-rs 2.7.5